# Question about Family of sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I have very little experience with Pure Math. Reading about sets for the first time from Topics in Algebra by Heinstein - Second Edition.

The book starts of with sets, unions, intersections etc & all of a sudden on Page 5, it talks about Family without saying what a Family is. I am quoting from the book below -

---

Given a set T we say that T serves as an index set for the family $\Bbb{F} = \{A_\alpha\}$ of sets if for every $\alpha \in T$ there exists a set of $A_\alpha$ in the family $\Bbb{F}$. The index set T can be any set, finite or infinite. Very often we use the set of nonnegative integers as an index set, but, we repeat, T can be any (nonempty) set.

---

Why is the concept of Family of sets introduced here? Can there not be an index set without a Family of Sets. You could have one set which indexes another set, right? That's what I got after googling for other references trying to understand this.

Comment: See [Family of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets): "a collection of any sets whatsoever is called a family of sets".

Comment: And see [Indexed family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family#Functions,_sets_and_families): $(A_i)_{ i \in I }$

Comment: A simple example of "index set" will be $\mathbb N = \{ 0,1,2,\ldots \}$ but the general idea is that a set $I$ whatever can be used to "index" a family.

Comment: In the same way as a succession of *reals* $(r_i)$ is a function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ where $f(i)=r_i$, so an indexed family of sets $(A_i)$ where $A_i \in A$ for every $i$ will be a function : $f : I \to A$ such that $f(i)=A_i$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - the link in your first comment indicates that a family is a collection of sets. The link in your second comment seems to indicate that a family is a just a set (singular) which has an Index set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA from the wikipedia link on family - ` a family, or indexed family, is informally a collection of objects` - a collection of objects is set (singular), right?

Comment: In set theory **everything** is a set; thus a collection of sets is a set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Any guesses on why does the book introduce the concept of an index to a family of sets before it introduces the concept of an Index to a singular set? It makes it rather confusing

Comment: @user93353 The description you encountered in the mentioned textbook is far from being anything formal and mathematically rigorous, so you shouldn't strive too vigorously to understand it at a level of formalism the text itself neither purports to nor in actual fact does have. A family $x$ is meant to describe a correspondence by means of which to every object in a particular set -- more specifically to every index $i$, generic element of the so-called index set say $I$ -- is associated a *unique* object, namely the component of index $i$ of family $x$ (component which one denotes by $x_i$).

Comment: @user93353 In other words, the notion of ''index set'' only makes sense in relation to a specified family, not to a single set or a collection of sets (which -- as Mauro ALLEGRANZA rightfully points out -- is itself yet another set).